# Display node author picture through tpl file

Tags: 7, users, theming, nodes

I am writing my custom node--blog.tpl.php for my Drupal7 based site. I want to print the author image of the blog so in my tpl file i include the following:

```
$user = user_load($user->uid);
  print theme_image_style(
                array(

                    'path' => $user->picture->uri,
                    'attributes' => array(
                        'class' => 'in-blog-user'
                    )
                )
            );
```

However, it does not display any image and i get a error as :

`The requested page "/sites/default/files/styles//public" could not be found`

What am i doing wrong?

Regards

PS: my pictures directory is "pictures"

Answer (score 3):

The following lines did it:

```
$user = user_load($uid);
print theme('user_picture', array('account' =>$user));
```

Comment: Please don't add follow up questions in the answers, if you have another question please ask it separately

Answer (score 0):

There is [Author Pane](http://drupal.org/project/author_pane)

> Author Pane is a block of information about a given user, like those
>   typically found on a forum post, but can be used in other places as
>   well. From core, it collects the user picture, name, join date, online
>   status, contact link, and profile information. In addition, any module
>   or theme can feed it more information via the preprocess system. All
>   of this information is then gathered and displayed using a template
>   file.

For the tabbed view you cold try [Quick Tabs](http://drupal.org/project/quicktabs)

> The Quick Tabs module allows you to create blocks of tabbed content,
>   specifically views, blocks, nodes* and other quicktabs*.